# "dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.desencrypt" 8byte encrypting limit issue in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql, obfuscation, database

i got a sql query that returns varchar2,
than i need to encrypt those results with "dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.desencrypt"
but the problem is it can only encrypt 8byte or its multiples and results are not always 8byte;

is there a solution to overcome this problem or any alternative encryption tool for pl/sql ?

here's the code;

```
DECLARE
TYPE name_array is table OF varchar2(100);
var_input  name_array;
var_key    varchar2(16) := 'Anahtar1'; 
var_enc    varchar2(1024);
var_dec    varchar2(1024);


cursor c1 is
SELECT owner FROM sys.all_objects;

BEGIN
open c1;
fetch c1 bulk collect into var_input;
close c1;       

FOR i IN var_input.FIRST .. var_input.LAST
LOOP
         dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.DESEncrypt(
        input_string     =>  var_input(i),
        key_string       =>  var_key,
        encrypted_string =>  var_enc);
    dbms_output.put_line('encrypted...');               
END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm) instead.

Comment: as i know, i cant use varchar2 in crypto

Comment: @Burak Atar - not directly, but you can [convert your string to raw](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_crypto.htm#i1004146)

Answer (score -1):

sql> EXECUTE enkripsi ('oh semoga nilaiku bagus');
enkripsi berhasil
string sebelum enkripsi : oh semoga nilaiku bagus
string sesudah enkripsi : oh s3mog4 n1l41ku b4gus
PL/SQL>EXECUTE enkripsi ('kyt kmnwxz zzbfr');
enkripsi gagal
PL/SQL procedure successfully comleted.